# Горизонтальная прокрутка для Text виджета

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

В данном примере горизонтальная полоса прокрутки рисуется справа внизу и не работает. Как отобразить вертикальную и горизонтальную полосу прокрутки на текстовом виджете чтобы они работали.

```
 from tkinter import *
    root = Tk()
    text = Text(width=20, height=7)
    text.pack(side=LEFT)
    scrollY = Scrollbar(command=text.yview,orient=VERTICAL)
    scrollY.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
    scrollX = Scrollbar(command=text.xview,orient=HORIZONTAL)
    scrollX.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', anchor='w')
    text.config(yscrollcommand=scrollY.set,xscrollcommand=scrollX.set)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
frame=Frame(root,width=300,height=300)
frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
text = Text(frame,width=20, height=7,wrap=NONE)
scrollX = Scrollbar(frame,command=text.xview,orient=HORIZONTAL)
scrollX.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
scrollY = Scrollbar(frame,command=text.yview,orient=VERTICAL)
scrollY.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
text.config(yscrollcommand=scrollY.set,xscrollcommand=scrollX.set)
text.pack(side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А как теперь чтобы растягивался вместе с окошком?)))))))

Comment: Нашел еще один способ

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(300,300)

txt_frm = tk.Frame(root, width=300, height=300)
txt_frm.grid(row=0, column=0)
txt_frm.grid_propagate(False)
txt_frm.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
txt_frm.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

txt = tk.Text(txt_frm, borderwidth=3, relief="sunken")
txt.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap=NONE)
txt.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)

scrollb = tk.Scrollbar(txt_frm,orient=HORIZONTAL, command=txt.xview)
scrollb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
txt['xscrollcommand'] = scrollb.set

scrollby = tk.Scrollbar(txt_frm, orient=VERTICAL, command=txt.yview)
scrollby.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
txt['yscrollcommand'] = scrollby.set

root.mainloop()
```